# Clarification on using spec.pgram in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series

Does anyone understand how the argument **"span"** is used in  **spec.pgram** in **R**? From the help menu, it provides the following examples:

```
spectrum(ldeaths)
spectrum(ldeaths, spans = c(3,5)) gives bandwidth= 0.241
spectrum(ldeaths, spans = c(5,7)) gives bandwidth= 0.363
spectrum(ldeaths, spans = 3)      gives bandwidth= 0.127
```

1. What do **c(3,5)** and **c(3,7)** or **spans=3** represent?
2. How the bandwidths are calculated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, read the help files.

```
help(spec.pgram)
```

> spans: vector of odd integers giving the widths of modified Daniell
>   smoothers to be used to smooth the periodogram.
>
> bandwidth: The equivalent bandwidth of the kernel smoother as defined
>   by Bloomfield (1976, page 201).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Bloomfield's book. But could you please elucidate the difference between span=3 vs span c(3,3)? I read the help file, but I don't get it.